# How loop through list for regression?

Tags: python, loops, linear-regression, finance, quantitative-finance

I am trying to loop over a list of stocks to obtain the coefficients via linear regression. I get the following (see image). If I try to apply the code without the for loop, so when I separately enter the tickers of the list, I do get results
(see image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKP7F.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALkwq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the list `tickers` using a `for` loop using the syntax:

```py
for ticker in tickers:
    # Do something here
    pass
```

This will return the string element from the list on each iteration so on the first iteration the value of `ticker` will be set to `'AAPL'`. You can then pass this to string concatenation to perform your OLS regression.

I've copied your code from the image to make it easier for you and attempted to write a functional version.

```py
tickers = ['AAPL', 'AMGN'] # Use your full list instead here

results_list = [] # Initialise list to store results

for ticker in tickers:
    model = smf.ols(ticker + '~+DJIA', data=df) # run OLS on stock
    results_list.append(model.fit(cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags':5}))

for i, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    model = smf.ols(ticker + '~+DJIA', data=df) 
    results_list.append(model.fit(cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags':5}))
    print(results_list[i].summary2()) # optionally print the results
```

Please note, without input data and your original code (for easy copy/pasting) it is hard to deliver a testing and working solution, but I hope the above gets you on the right track.